# space delimited arguments to shell script

Tags: regex, linux, shell, plsql

my requirement is to call shell script from plsql procedure and pass arguments from plsql to shell script.
The problem I am facing now is, if the argument contains any space in between then the shell script treats it as separate argument values.

The input from pl sql to shell script  is as follows

```
abc@xyz.com##ace321##https://companyurl.com XRX_Test,AL 
LDG,Test,Test,false,2,5 XRX_Test,AL LDG,Test1,Test1,false,2,5
```

Here **Arg1** is `"abc@xyz.com##ace321##https:companyurl.com"` and   **Arg2** is `"XXX_Test,AL LDG,Test1,Test1,false,2,5"` and **Arg3** is `"XXX_Test2,AL LDG,Test1,Test1,false,2,5"`

In shell script I am trying as follows

```
echo "Process argument begins"  
    echo "The total arg:" "$#"  
    echo " Received arguments:" "$@"
    for l_temp in "$@"
        do
            echo "arguments:" + ' "' "$l_temp" '"'
            # EXTRACT_NAME+=' "' "$l_temp" '"'
            EXTRACT_NAME+=' "'
            EXTRACT_NAME+="$l_temp"
            EXTRACT_NAME+='"'
        done
    echo "Complete List" "$EXTRACT_NAME"
    echo "Process argument ends"
```

and output from above shell script is as follows(although i am passing only 3 arguments, because of space I am getting 5 arguments)

```
Process argument begins
The total arg: 5
 Received arguments: abc@xyz.com##ace321##https://companyurl.com XRX_Test,AL LDG,Test,Test,false,2,5 XRX_Test1,AL LDG,Test1,Test1,false,2,5
arguments: +  " abc@xyz.com##ace321##https://companyurl.com "
arguments: +  " XRX_Test,AL "
arguments: +  " LDG,Test,Test,false,2,5 "
arguments: +  " XRX_Test1,AL "
arguments: +  " LDG,Test1,Test1,false,2,5 "
Complete List  "abc@xyz.com##ace321##https://companyurl.com" "XRX_Test,AL" "LDG,Test,Test,false,2,5" "XRX_Test1,AL" "LDG,Test1,Test1,false,2,5"
Process argument ends
```

But actual o/p required is as follows

```
Process argument begins
The total arg: 3
 Received arguments: abc@kbace.com##ace321##https:companyurl.com XXX_Test,AL LDG,Test1,Test1,false,2,5 XXX_Test2,AL LDG,Test1,Test1,false,2,5
arguments: +  " abc@xyz.com##ace321##https:companyurl.com "
arguments: +  " XXX_Test,AL LDG,Test1,Test1,false,2,5 "
arguments: +  " XXX_Test2,AL LDG,Test1,Test1,false,2,5 "
Complete List  "abc@xyz.com##ace321##https:companyurl.com" "XXX_Test,AL LDG,Test1,Test1,false,2,5" "XXX_Test2,AL LDG,Test1,Test1,false,2,5"
Process argument ends
```

Can some one help me on this ? what change I need to do in my shell script to avoid space or any special character? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When passing the arguments to your script, just put them between quotes:

```
bash script.sh "abc@xyz.com##ace321##https:companyurl.com" "XXX_Test,AL LDG,Test1,Test1,false,2,5" "XXX_Test2,AL LDG,Test1,Test1,false,2,5"
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried that approach. I have append quotes to my arguments in pl sql and sending but when i am receiving in shell script it coming without quotes hence the problem. As i mentioned above when i echo $@ it prints arguments without quotes and causing issue.

Comment: I have tried launching the script from shell and it finds 3 arguments, maybe the quotes need to be escaped?

Comment: Yes, it works fine when i run the shell from command prompt and pass arguments with double quotes. That is the reason i am appending quotes before passing it to shell script. But some how i am not able to get quotes when i receive it in shell script

Comment: Escape the double-quotes by adding a backslash before the `"` character. In other words, instead of just adding `"` you should add `\"`. Best of luck.

Comment: Do you mean in pl sql? Say L_EXTRACT has my input then This is what i have tried L_TEMP_VAL:=q'[\"]'||L_EXTRACT||q'[\"]';  but still facing same issue. Thanks

Comment: Hi, is there any other way i can achieve this requirement? This is critical for me, if some one suggest me the way then that is really help full. thanks